# Types names as string to std::tuple instance

Tags: c++, templates, runtime, compile-time, stdtuple

I have an `**std::vector<std::string>**` witch contains the names of types example `**["int","float","string"]**`, i want to create an std::tuple instance that reflect the vector types names, the `**std::tuple**` for the **`std::vector`** in example would be of type **`std::tuple<int,float,std::string>`**

```
template <typename... Ts>
std::tuple<Ts...> tupleCat(std::vector<std::string> names){
     //TODO: what i should put here ?

}
```

Comment: fwiw, getting the tuple is much more involved than getting a single type as in the dupe. It can be done, but I would reconsider if there is not a easier solution to the actual problem you are trying to solve

Comment: Thanks for answering, actually I tried  some ways but no one works, if u have a suggestion it would be great

Comment: as I said, I suggest to reconsider what is your acutual problem and to find a different way to solve it. The approach in the duplicate quesiton is what you can do, but due to the combinatorial complexity it either requires some clever code generation or to write lots of boilerplate code